# Vts Testcases for android

Tags: android

Vts setup completed for my Ubuntu.But test cases I don't know how to write so please suggest the document.

Another one issue when I run the Vts testcases "AnnouncementRegisterListener()" testcases ignored and failed so please answer shortly